# Query String auto Uppercase in recordset DoQuery C# SAP

Tags: c#, sapb1

I have an error when running, this is an example code:

```
oForm = (SAPbouiCOM.Form)oApplication.Forms.ActiveForm;
SAPbobsCOM.Recordset oRecordset = (SAPbobsCOM.Recordset)oCompany.GetBusinessObject(SAPbobsCOM.BoObjectTypes.BoRecordset);
startdate = EditText0.Value.ToString();
enddate = EditText1.Value.ToString();
string QueryStr = "";
QueryStr = "SELECT ";
QueryStr += "CardCode,";
QueryStr += "CardName";
QueryStr += " From ocrd T0 limit 10";
oRecordset.DoQuery(QueryStr);
```

And this error

[image]

can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hana will convert any table/column/view names to upper case unless you quote them. So for example you need to quote every field name with speech marks:

```
QueryStr += "\"CardCode\",";
```

You can get away without quoting the B1 system table names because they're all upper case anyway.

Comment: yeah right, I just realized it and the problem is solved with this QueryStr += @"T0.""CardCode"","; 
but thanks for your help daz